# Code is making syntax errors

Tags: syntax, row, lines

Make programm, that asks from user his name and number of lines for the incoming shape.
For example.

```
Peeter and 6, the example wil be :
Peeter shape:

* * * * * * 
*         * 
*         * 
*         * 
*         * 
* * * * * *
```

So my code is:

```
def square():
    row = int(input('Insert number of rows'))
    line = len(input('Insert your name'))

    for r in range(1, (row+1), 1):
        if r == 1 or r == rida:
            for v in range(1, (line+1), 1):
                print('*', end=' ')
        else:
            print('*', end=' ')
            for v in range(2, row, 1):
                print(' ', end=' ')
            print('*', end=' ')
        print()

square()
```

But the problem is, it gives me syntaxerror and I am out of ideas how to fix it.

Thank you for your help and time for advance.

Nika